Two numerical sequences
Two numerical sequences made by me. Make sure to provide reasoning.

90,81,65,29,9,?

46656, 823543, 16777216, ?



First is one is:

 9

Reason

 To generate the next term in the sequence you 1) multiply the first two digits of its previous term 2) add the first digit to that 3) then take away the result from that number.

 90: 9x0 + 9 = 9 then 90 - 9 = 81
 81: 8x1 + 8 = 16 then 81 - 16 = 65
 65: 6x5 + 6 = 36 then 65 - 36 = 29
 29: 2x9 + 2 = 20 then 29 - 20 = 9
 09: 0x9 + 0 = 0 then 9-0 = 9

Second one is

 9^9 or 387420489

Reason

 The prior sequence is going 6^6, 7^7, 8^8. The number and its exponential is going up +1 each time.

